PrimeVue OverlayPanel dont open when call after await
I have a problem with the OverlayPanel component of the PrimeVue library, in the following code:
MainView.vue
<template>
    <button @click="search">
        show
    </button>

    <OverlayPanel ref="op" appendTo="body">
        {{ data }}
    </OverlayPanel>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import OverlayPanel from 'primevue/overlaypanel';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const op = ref();
const data = ref();

const search = async (e: Event) => {
    const response = await Service.fetchData('');

    op.value.show(e);
};
</script>

The problem lies in the following block:
const search = async (e: Event) => {
    const response = await Service.fetchData('');
    op.value.show(e);
};

If I call op.value.show(e) after the await call, the OverlayPanel component is not shown (dont work). But if I call it before the await it does show it.
This does work:
const search = async (e: Event) => {
    op.value.show(e);
    const response = await Service.fetchData('');
};

This does not.
const search = async (e: Event) => {
    const response = await Service.fetchData('');
    op.value.show(e);
};

I need the op.value.show(e) instruction to be there after the response is obtained from the service.
Thanks for your help.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, it looks unreproducible. show() works in a straightforward way https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/components/lib/overlaypanel/OverlayPanel.vue#L98 and isn't supposed to be affected by timing, especially since search  is called asynchronously any way. This will naturally happen if there's a problem with fetchData

You should wait for the next DOM update. you should use nextTick. This will wait for the next DOM Update. Check the example below I hope this will solve your problem.
const search = async (e: Event) => {
    op.value.show(e);
    await nextTick();
    const response = await Service.fetchData('');
};


nextTick is necessary the operations that rely on DOM. This is not the case
